# Circuit design for electric strike protection

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-design

I want to design a circuit ( maybe it already exists), that functions like this. It will have an input of 12VAC/50Hz that it will act as a control signal and power input , then a dry contact of a relay activates for 2 seconds (it will be a 10A relay) and then off. When the 12VAC control voltage is given for more than 2 seconds (i.e. the input voltage is stuck) then the dry contact needs to shut down until 12VAC voltage is disconnected. Also i want buzzer to sound for warning (stuck input voltage). All this to work in a loop.

This circuit will be used in a audio door phone system so it will protect the electric strike from burning if an "open door" button is stuck.

How can I make it for a low price and what parts I need?

Comment: This sounds very familiar. Have you asked the same question before?

Comment: A little bit too broad question? But have a look at bridge rectifiers and  "555 one-shot" as a start.

Comment: Please make an attempt of your own first. As a start you may look for a "relay delayed turn on" circuit. The "NC" contact of such a relay could be useful.